# detachedWithStdio flutter not running data

Tags: flutter, powershell, dart, cmd

I am trying to get the detachedWithStdio (detached standard IO) to build as text. It works for some things, but it does not work for powershell.exe. here's my code for context

```
Future<String> _powershell(int numberOfDrive) async {

    int num = numberOfDrive-2;
//  var shell = new Shell();
//  final cmd = await shell.start('Get-Disk', arguments: [r'foreach { $_ | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Format-List }']);
//  await cmd.stdout.toString();
//  print(await cmd.stdout.transform(Utf8Decoder()).toList());
    return _runcmd(
        "powershell.exe",
        ['echo hello joshua'],
        '',
    );
}
  
static Future<String> _runcmd(String executable,
    List<String> arguments,
    String regExpSource,) async {
    String id = '';
    try {
        final process = await Process.start(
            executable,
            arguments,
            mode: ProcessStartMode.detachedWithStdio,
        );

        final result = await process.stdout.transform(Utf8Decoder(allowMalformed: true)).toList();
        for (var element in result) {
            final item = element.replaceAll(
                RegExp('[\n | ^\w]'), ''
            );
            if (item.isNotEmpty) {
                id = item;
                print(id);
            }
        }
    } on Exception catch (_) {id = "could not run";}

    return id;
}
```

I have the rest set up as a future builder that grabs the data from powershell.exe and posts it to a list or a single string depending on what I need. it works for commands like wmic, but not powershell.exe. when I run the runcmd future with inheritStdio and When I look at the run console, it works. It just doesn't post to the app.